# If $C_0, C_1, C_2, .., C_n$ are the binomial coefficients in the expansion of $(1+x)^n$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

If $C_0, C_1, C_2,...,C_n$ are the binomial coefficients in the expansion of $(1+x)^n$, prove that:
$$C_{r}.C_{n} + C_{r+1}.C_{n-1} +......+ C_{n}.C_{r} = C(2n, n+r) =\dfrac {(2n)!}{(n-r)! (n+r)!}$$

Is there any way to approach this sort of questions using calculus (derivatives or integration)?

Comment: Your equation to prove is a special case of [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity), for your reference.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth, How does that help?

Comment: It gives you a term to help you search with. Like you can try searching for "Vandermonde identity calculus proof" or whatever. It would be harder to search for things like this if you didn't know the name of the identity.

Answer (score 1):

THis suffices to differentiate $(1+x)^{2n}=(1+x)^n(1+x)^n $   $n+r$ times.

Differentiating the right side first,

By (General Leibniz rule), it's derivative is given by differentiating the first part $k$ times and the second part $(n+r)-k$ times.

It's derivative is given by $\sum_{k=0}^{n+r} {{n}\choose{k}}((1+x)^n)^{(k)}((1+x)^n)^{(n+r-k)}$

$=\sum_{k=0}^{n-r} {{n}\choose{k+r}} ((1+x)^n)^{(r+k)}((1+x)^n)^{(n-k)}$

Evaluating at $x=0$,

$=\sum_{k=0}^{n-r} \dfrac{(n+r)!}{(k+r)!(n-k)!} \dfrac{n!}{(n-r-k)!}\dfrac{n!}{k!}$

$=(n+r)! \sum_{k=0}^{n-r} \dfrac{n!}{(k+r)!(n-r-k)!} \dfrac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}$

$=(n+r)! \sum_{k=0}^{n-r} {{n}\choose{k+r}}{{n}\choose{n-k}}$

Differentiating left side gives $(n+r)!{{2n}\choose{n+r}}$

Giving the desired equality.

Comment: @L KM,How do we know to differentiate $n+r$ times?

Comment: I actually work using generating function implicitly. Which does not require differentiation. Hence we can compare each coefficient easily with that.

Comment: The proof is as follows, $(1+x)^{2n}=(1+x)^n(1+x)^n$. Look at the coefficient of $x^{n+r}$ on each side. On the left side, it is ${2n}\choose{n+r}$. On the right hand side, it is exactly the sum you stated, $\sum_{k=0}^{n-r} {{n}\choose{k+r}}{{n}\choose{n-k}}$

Comment: @L KM, Would you please take time to mention the general strategy to solve these sorts of problems using calculus?

Comment: To be more precise, the attain $x^{n+r}$ on the right hand side $(1+x)^n(1+x)^n=(\sum_k {{n}\choose{k}} x^k)\cdot (\sum_k {{n}\choose{k}} x^k) $, we need $x^k$ from the left sum, $x^{n+r-k}$ from the right sum. Note that $n\ge k, n\ge (n+r-k)$, hence $n\ge k \ge r$.

Comment: General strategy is to work more on generating function. There are of course general algorithm using computer to solve these problem, but not so useful for non-IT guys.

Comment: @L KM, what simplification did you do just before the step $x=0$

Comment: $\sum_{k=0}^{n+r} {{n}\choose{k}}((1+x)^n)^{(k)}((1+x)^n)^{(n+r-k)}$, if $k \lt r$, then $(n+r-k) \gt n$,  $((1+x)^n)^{(n+r-k)}=0$. If $k\gt n$, $((1+x)^n)^{(k)}=0$, hence we need only to take range of $k$ from $ r$ to $n$.

Answer (score 1):

We can solve this problem using algebra without needs for differentiation or integration. It is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^k$ in a series. This way we can write for instance
\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{k}=[x^k](1+x)^n\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> We start with the right-hand side and obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\frac{(2n)!}{(n-r)!(n+r)!}}&=\binom{2n}{n+r}\\
> &=[x^{n+r}](1+x)^{2n}\tag{2}\\
> &=[x^{n+r}]\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^k\sum_{l=0}^n\binom{n}{l}x^l\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}[x^{n+r-k}]\sum_{l=0}^n\binom{n}{l}x^l\tag{4}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{n+r-k}\tag{5}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{k=r}^n\binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{n+r-k}}\tag{6}
> \end{align*}
>
> and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (2) we write $\binom{2n}{n+r}$ using the *coefficient of* operator according to (1).
- In (3) we write $(1+x)^{2n}=(1+x)^n(1+x)^n$ and expand.
- In (4) we use the rule $[x^{p+q}]A(x)=[x^p]x^{-q}A(x)$.
- In (5) we select the coefficient of $x^{n+r-k}$.
- In (6) we note that $\binom{p}{q}=0$ if $q>p$ and set the lower index consequently to $k=r$.

Comment: How did you get $(1)$?

Comment: @pi-π: From the binomial expansion $(1+x)^n=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}x^j$.